# Chef warning about platform and version running Coverage for ChefSpec

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I am relatively new to Chef and very new to ChefSpec. I'm trying to run `Coverage` to get ChefSpec coverage using the `spec_helper.rb` file below:

```
require 'chefspec'
require 'chefspec/berkshelf'

ChefSpec::Coverage.start! do
  add_output do |reportOutput|
    File.open( "coverage.json","w" ) do |f| 
      f.puts(reportOutput[:total])
      f.puts(reportOutput[:touched])
      f.puts(reportOutput[:coverage])
      f.puts(reportOutput[:untouched_resources])
      f.puts(reportOutput[:all_resources])
    end 
  end 
end
```

When I run `rspec`, I get this in the output:

```
WARNING: you must specify a 'platform' and 'version' to your ChefSpec 
Runner and/or Fauxhai constructor, in the future omitting these will 
become a hard error. A list of available platforms is available at 
https://github.com/chefspec/fauxhai/blob/master/PLATFORMS.md
.WARNING: you must specify a 'platform' and 'version' to your ChefSpec
Runner and/or Fauxhai constructor, in the future omitting these will 
become a hard error. A list of available platforms is available at 
https://github.com/chefspec/fauxhai/blob/master/PLATFORMS.md
```

I'm not sure how to specify the platform and version in the `Coverage` - I saw some examples on how to do it with `ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your spec so I can't say specifically, but you must pass `platform` and `version` options to your Runner constructor, just like the error says. For example `ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '16.04')`. You can also specify it once globally for all tests in your spec helper, instructions are in the ChefSpec README.